# Make the second div be next to the first div when using toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle

When toggling, the second div appears on the bottom first then appears on top. Is there any way to just make the second div be on the left of the first div when toggling?

Thanks in advance.

```
http://jsfiddle.net/KFmLv/1862/
```

html

### Slide toggle from right to left and left to right.

```
<hr/>
<p>
    <select class="mySelect">
        <option value="right">Right</option>
        <option value="left">Left</option>
        <option value="up">Up</option>
        <option value="down">Down</option>
    </select>
    <select class="mySelect2">
        <option value="left">Left</option>
        <option value="right">Right</option>
        <option value="up">Up</option>
        <option value="down">Down</option>
    </select>
    <button id="button" class="myButton">Toggle</button>
</p>
<div id="myDiv">
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
    <p>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).</p>
</div>
<div id="myDiv2">
    <p>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).</p>
</div>
```

javascript

```
$(".myButton").click(function () {

// Set the effect type
var effect = 'slide';

// Set the options for the effect type chosen
var options = {
    direction: $('.mySelect').val()
};
var options2 = {
    direction: $('.mySelect2').val()
};
// Set the duration (default: 400 milliseconds)
var duration = 500;

$('#myDiv').toggle(effect, options, duration);
$('#myDiv2').toggle(effect, options2, duration);
```

});

Answer (score 1):

Wrap `#myDiv` and `#myDiv2` in an element with relative position and give `absolute` position to `#myDiv` and `#myDiv2`.

CSS:

```
#myDiv,#myDiv2{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
}
.relative{
    position:relative;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="relative">
    <div id="myDiv">...</div>
    <div id="myDiv2">...</div>
</div>
```

[**See updated fiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/KFmLv/1886/)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the updated jsfiddle with some changes

```
'http://jsfiddle.net/KFmLv/1890/'
```

Comment: Worked perfectly too! Thanks so much! :D